# Consider the vectors $x_1=(2,1),x_2=(4,3),x_3=(7,-3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Consider the vectors $x_1=(2,1),x_2=(4,3),x_3=(7,-3)$:

(a) Show that $x_1$ and $x$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

(b) Why must $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be linearly dependent?

(c) What is the dimension of $\textrm{Span}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$?

Especially for question (c), I just don't understand how to find the dimension of a Span.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR8Fu.jpg)

Comment: Hint: (c) follows from (a).

Comment: The vector space spanned by these vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so its dimension is at most $2$. Now, in part $\left(a\right)$, you've (hopefully) already shown that two of them span the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so the three of them clearly do as well (by adding more vectors, you're only enlarging the span)...

Comment: Further, knowing that two of the vectors alone span $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can express the third as a linear combination of these two...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent.  The dimenson of $\mathbb R^2$ is 2.  Any two linearly independent vectors from $\mathbb R^2$ spans $\mathbb R^2$

Since $x_3$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\{x_1,x_2\}$ span $\mathbb R^2$ then $x_3$ is in Span $(x_1,x_2)$

or, more directly $x_3 = 12x_1 - 17 x_2$

Again, any two of the 3 vectors spans $\mathbb R^2$ the third is redundant.  Nonethless Span $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is $\mathbb R^2$